# How can I print and return within the same line?

Tags: c++, syntax

I know that something like this is possible, I just forgot how to do it properly.

```
if (true)
    printf("something"), return;
```

Comment: @Vojin...Call function (which returns) from the printf . for example : printf("something" , functioncall);

Comment: What's the return type of the function?   And (assuming the type is not `void`) what value do you intend to return?

Comment: Return type is std::list<int>

Comment: @Peter Good call, I never thought OP might be in a non-`void` function. Indeed, you need to return the expected type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return` is not an expression, so it cannot be an operand of the comma operator.

Here is a (trivially) one-line version that works:

```
if (true) { printf("something"); return; }
```

(Note: one-line-ness is overrated. Write for readability, not brevity, and if they coincide, win-win. Granted, I myself should follow my advice more often...)

EDIT: You might be thinking of some variation of

```
if (true) return (void) printf("something"); // for void functions
if (true) return printf("something"), 0;     // for an e.g. int function
```

which works, but is ugly and hacky, as it obscures what is being returned. I don't endorse their use.

Comment: I thought of something like that, but the syntax doesn`t work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the return type is `std::list<int>` then you need to return `std::list<int>`. You can't simply return nothing, which is what your code is trying to do.

A quick fix will be:

```
if (true)
{
    printf("something");
    return {};
}
```

Using [brace initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/initializing-classes-and-structs-without-constructors-cpp?view=vs-2019) this will return an empty `std::list<int>`. Then whatever calls this function will have to check for an empty list.

---

In C++17 we have [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) that allows us to to return an optional value: it can be value or no value.

So you could change your function signature to return `std::optional<std::list<int>>` like this:

```
std::optional<std::list<int>> getList()
{
    if (true)
        return {};

    ...
}
```

Here we are returning a [nullopt_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t) for the true case. Then the code calling this function will have to check a value is returned:

```
auto l = getList();
if (l.has_value())                 //or simply if (l)
{
    //Do something with l.value()  //or simply *l
}
```

Her's a little example: https://godbolt.org/z/SXbZSq